# Sorting Days of the week with their time

Tags: java, date

I want the sort starting on Sunday at 00:00. My problem is that the zero of this code starts on Thursday at 8:00. I sort by getting the minutes, but zero starts at Thu 8:00.

This is my code so far.

```
String[] lines = S.split("\n");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lines));

int longest = 0;
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE HH:mm-HH:mm", Locale.US);
        long diffMinutes;
        diffMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(
                            formatter.parse(lines[i + 1]).getTime() - 
                            formatter.parse(lines[i]).getTime());
        if (longest < diffMinutes) {
            longest = (int) diffMinutes;
        }
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return longest;
```

The function takes a String like this

```
"Mon 01:00-23:00\\nTue 01:00-23:00\\nWed 01:00-23:00\\nThu 01:00-23:00\\nFri 01:00-23:00\\nSat 01:00-23:00\\nSun 01:00-21:00"
```

The program slices the string and stores it in array lines, then I'm trying to sort it.

Comment: Try debugging the value of the dates you get from `formatter.parse` .

Comment: Are you sure your splitting of the input `String` is working correctly? I mean does it really *slice* the `String`?

Comment: @Arnaud I did. that's how I know that 0 is thu 8:00 but I want to set it to Sun 00:00 so that I can determine which is ealiest from there. have any clue how?

Comment: @deHaar fortunately it does the job pretty well :D

Comment: Nice... It does not work in my IDE, but that may just be my fault ;-) However, why don't you parse them to a `java.time.LocalDateTime`, which is easily comparable and sortable? **Oh, now I see why you don't:** they are periods...

Comment: @deHaar actually somebody suggested that so I've been looking at the API now.

Comment: @KarlGarcia concerning the splitting of the `String`: Is your input really a `String` containing `"\\n"` rather than `"\n"`?

Comment: Just another question: Do you want to sort them by day of week or by length of the duration? In the latter case, do you want to sort them ascending or descending?

Comment: right now, I just want to sort it earliest to latest starting Sun 00:00 but descending vice-versa can be good.

Comment: @deHaar Yes your right! I think the copy pasting automatically added the other "\" on the process

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: A `Date` is *one* point in time. What would be the expected outcome of having `HH:mm` *twice* in your format pattern string?

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem may be solved by applying some more splitting, due to your `String` representation of the period being of the form *from-to* instead of an absolute value like *1320 (minutes)*. I would use `java.time`, especially `LocalTime` and `Duration` for proper calculating and comparing.

My code basically does the following (see code comments) making use of helper methods:

1. splits the input by `"\n"`
2. splits every result of the first step by space in order to separate the day of week from the times of day
3. splits the second result of the second split by `"-"` in order to get the times of day
4. converts the results into appropriate objects
5. stores them in an appropriate data structure
6. finds the maximum durations

This is what I came up with:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class WeekdayDurationHandler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // input String splitting...
        String input = "Mon 01:00-23:00\nTue 01:00-23:00\nWed 01:00-23:00\nThu 01:00-23:00\nFri 01:00-23:00\nSat 01:00-23:00\nSun 01:00-21:00";
        String[] times = input.split("\n");

        // data structure for holding the durations per day
        Map<DayOfWeek, Duration> weekdayDurations = new TreeMap<>();

        // the result of the first splitting is unparseable, that's why some more
        // splitting is applied
        for (String s : times) {
            // separate the day of week from the time duration
            String[] sp = s.split(" ");
            // split the duration into "from" and "to" (time of day)
            String[] tp = sp[1].split("-");
            // parse the day of week into an appropriate object
            DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = parseDayOfWeek(sp[0]);
            // parse the times of day into appropriate objects
            LocalTime localTimeFrom = LocalTime.parse(tp[0]);
            LocalTime localTimeTo = LocalTime.parse(tp[1]);
            // calculate the duration between "from" and "to" time of day
            Duration duration = Duration.between(localTimeFrom, localTimeTo);
            // store them in the data structure
            weekdayDurations.put(dayOfWeek, duration);
        }

        // print them
        weekdayDurations.forEach((DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, Duration duration) -> {
            System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.getDefault()) + ": "
                    + duration.toHours() + " hours (" + duration.toMinutes() + " minutes)");
        });

        System.out.println("######################################################");

        // then print the maximum durations found
        findMaxDurationsFrom(weekdayDurations).forEach((DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, Duration duration) -> {
            System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.getDefault()) + ": "
                    + duration.toHours() + " hours (" + duration.toMinutes() + " minutes)");
        });
    }

    private static DayOfWeek parseDayOfWeek(String weekday) {
        switch (weekday.toLowerCase()) {
        case "mon":
            return DayOfWeek.MONDAY;
        case "tue":
            return DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;
        case "wed":
            return DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;
        case "thu":
            return DayOfWeek.THURSDAY;
        case "fri":
            return DayOfWeek.FRIDAY;
        case "sat":
            return DayOfWeek.SATURDAY;
        case "sun":
            return DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unparsable weekday: \"" + weekday + "\"");
        }
    }

    private static Map<DayOfWeek, Duration> findMaxDurationsFrom(Map<DayOfWeek, Duration> weekDurations) {
        final Map<DayOfWeek, Duration> maxDurations = new TreeMap<>();
        // find the maximum duration as a reference for all equal durations
        Duration maxDuration = findMaxDuration(weekDurations);
        // go through all durations and store those equal to maxDuration (no matter what day of week)
        weekDurations.forEach((DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, Duration duration) -> {
            if (duration.equals(maxDuration)) {
                maxDurations.put(dayOfWeek, duration);
            }
        });

        return maxDurations;
    }

    private static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V findMaxDuration(Map<K, V> map) {
        Entry<K, V> maxEntry = Collections.max(map.entrySet(),
                (Entry<K, V> e1, Entry<K, V> e2) -> e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue()));
        return maxEntry.getValue();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps…